# C++ сигнатуры методов

Tags: c++

Мой уровень С++ но начальном этапе и у меня возник вопрос. 
Как вообще можно что-то понять из этой сигнатуры метода? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я стараюсь понять, что мне нужно передать в эту функцию и не могу понять ничего. 
Что посоветуете делать с этим? Как правильно нужно читать эту сигнатуру или возможно у кого-то есть какие-то репозитории с открытым кодом С++, где можно учиться просто читать и понимать его?

Comment: Дело привычки :) А главное - думаю, что вам это совсем не нужно, в чем у вас ошибка - должно быть понятно из первых сообщений... А вообще - как-то раз компилятор (не у меня :)) выдал сообщение об ошибке в 18 мегабайт, если верить авторам "Шаблонов С++". Специфика.

Comment: За исключением редких случаев, нет никакой необходимости расшифровывать эту сигнатуру. Понимания того, что речь идет о `getline`, обычно более чем достаточно.

Comment: Да, С++ похож на головоломку. Возможно лучшим решением будет вообще не тратить на его изучение свое время.

Comment: Для VC++ стоит почитать здесь: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56h2zst2.aspx

Comment: @avp почему не стоит?  меня не пугают его трудности и нужен правильный подход к изучению. пока что, это сложно, вот я и спросил, может у кого-то были какие-то методы .. как они учили этот язык.

Comment: Потому что сложившаяся практика программирования на нем уже очевидно нарушает [KISS принцип](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Попробуйте этот ужас декомпозировать. Известно, что это функция:

```
возвращаемый_тип имя_функции(тип_аргумента1 арг1, 
                             тип_аргумента2 арг2
                             ...)
```

далее смотрим, что возвращаемый тип - это ссылка, как и аргументы:

```
возвращаемый_тип& имя_функции(тип_аргумента1 &арг1, 
                              тип_аргумента2 &арг2
                              ...)
```

Затем двигайтесь дальше, что функция - шаблонная, т.е. перед именем у нее стоят аргументы-типы в скобках `<T,K>`, аналогично и возвращаемый тип c аргументами - тоже шаблонные, получаем:

```
возвращаемый_тип<T,K>& имя_функции<T,K>(тип_аргумента1<T,K> &арг1, 
                                        тип_аргумента2<T,K> &арг2
                                        ...)
```

И, наконец, перед именами типов стоит пространство имен `std`:

```
std::возвращаемый_тип<T,K>& имя_функции<T,K>(std::тип_аргумента1<T,K> &арг1, 
                                             std::тип_аргумента2<T,K> &арг2
                                             ...)
```

Выделяя все эти составные части мешанина букв и символов обретает ожидаемые очертания. Это действительно приходит с опытом чтения кода на С++.

Comment: что-то такое и пробовал, но пока что как-то сложно особенно с шаблонами и тем как их читать.

Comment: @DimaKhodan, продолжайте) Читать самому - это еще одно дело, забавнее становится с выводом типов - как компилятор *понял* написанное